# Pandas groupby and average across unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe

```
   ID ID2  SCORE  X  Y
0   0   a     10  1  2
1   0   b     20  2  3
2   0   b     20  3  4
3   0   b     30  4  5
4   1   c      5  5  6
5   1   d      6  6  7
```

What I would like to do, is to groupby `ID` and `ID2` and to average the `SCORE` taking into consideration only UNIQUE scores.

Now, if I use the standard `df.groupby(['ID', 'ID2'])['SCORE'].mean()` I would get 23.33~, where what I am looking for is a score of 25.

I know I can filter out `X` and `Y`, drop the duplicates and do that, but I want to keep them as they are relevant.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If i understand correctly:

```
In [41]: df.groupby(['ID', 'ID2'])['SCORE'].agg(lambda x: x.unique().sum()/x.nunique())
Out[41]:
ID  ID2
0   a      10
    b      25
1   c       5
    d       6
Name: SCORE, dtype: int64
```

or bit easier:

```
In [43]: df.groupby(['ID', 'ID2'])['SCORE'].agg(lambda x: x.unique().mean())
Out[43]:
ID  ID2
0   a      10
    b      25
1   c       5
    d       6
Name: SCORE, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It should be 25, not 35, as in the average of 20 and 30

Comment: `lambda x: x.unique().sum()/x.nunique())` does seem to work!

Comment: @bluesummers, yeah, i came to the same solution... :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the unique scores within groups of `('ID', 'ID2')` by dropping duplicates before hand.

```
cols = ['ID', 'ID2', 'SCORE']
d1 = df.drop_duplicates(cols)
d1.groupby(cols[:-1]).SCORE.mean()

ID  ID2
0   a      10
    b      25
1   c       5
    d       6
Name: SCORE, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
In [108]: df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'ID2', 'SCORE']).groupby(['ID', 'ID2'])['SCORE'].mean()
Out[108]:
ID  ID2
0   a      10
    b      25
1   c       5
    d       6
Name: SCORE, dtype: int64
```